# ASP.net C# GridView to html table not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itext

So I have this on my mark up:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ItemType="IR_InfantRecord.Models.Immunization" DataKeyNames="ImmunizationNumber" SelectMethod="patientImmunGrid_GetData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            ...
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmpName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Emp.EmpName%>"
                        runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text="<%# Item.Emp.Check%>"
                        runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:DynamicField DataField="Status" />
                <asp:DynamicField DataField="DateTaken" />            

            ...
        </asp:GridView>
```

and here on my .cs class:

```
public static string ConvertGVToHTML(GridView gv)
    {
        string html = "<table>";
        //add header row
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
            html += "<td>" + gv.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        //add rows
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int j = 0; j < gv.Columns.Count; j++)
                html += "<td>" + gv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
        return html;
    }
```

Which I found here on stackoverflow,The header works fine, but the rows are returning null. Im using this to print the gridview to pdf using ITextSharp.

This method also works with other gridview. I dont know why it returns null on this specific gv.

Comment: Are you sure your gridview have rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a TemplateField with a Label, the value is not in the cell text but in the Label control (which is the second control of the cell, after a Literal control):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    html += "<tr>";

    for (int j = 0; j < gv.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        TableCell cell = gv.Rows[i].Cells[j];

        html += "<td>";

        if (cell.Controls.Count > 1 && cell.Controls[1] is Label)
        {
            Label lblValue = cell.Controls[1] as Label;
            html += lblValue.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            html += cell.Text;
        }

        html += "</td>";
    }

    html += "</tr>";
}
```

By the way, I kept the string concatenation technique as shown in your code but it would be preferable to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry, I just made the correction for the `tr` tags before noticing that your edit was "pending" (first time someone edits one of my answers).

Comment: It's okay! Thank you again!!